# "Native libraries are not up-to-date. Please run ndk-build manually."

Tags: android-ndk

H|i All,

I am trying to compile fbreaderj based on the documentation provided, but stopped at the "ant release/or ant debug" with error msg says:

"Native libraries are not up-to-date. Please run ndk-build manually."

please note that ndk-build went thru with no errors, and i am running under windows and sdk android-19

please advise ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

change a single line 289 in build/core/definitions.mk from

$1: $$(__ndk_file_dir)

to

$1: | $$(__ndk_file_dir)

I found this patch here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/EFA21mVVqH0/7gIJrmzK41EJ